# How to document javascript unit test files using jsdoc?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdoc

I have a react project and I am using jest to write unit and integration tests.
I want to use jsdoc to document those files.

But dont know how ? didn't find anything in the jsdoc page.
Can anyone help me with an example if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Documenting unit tests isn't an appropriate and clear way. Put simply, I'd rather create efficient test suites along with pretty clear explanations, in order to avoid any specific documentation in tests. Afterwards, the tests' suites will resemble to a complete documentation and they'll also tell about what the current method is doing.

Here is an example to demonstrate the stuff above with Jest:

```
desscribe('<ComponentName />', () => {
   describe('button click', () => {
      it('calls exampleFunction', () => {
         expect(exampleFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
   });
});
```

I'm not an expert in integration testing, but if you'd really like to stay with the point to document your tests, the page of *jsdoc* is quite straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0):

To generate **unit test report** like **JSDoc** for your unit test cases, use `coverage` flag on your `npm test`.

Lets say you wrote some test cases and want to generate report along with test case result and details, Here is an example with flag.

`npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll=false --coverageDirectory=../outside_folder_path/_test_report_/`

`--coverage` flag will create **coverage** folder inside of your project root and generate report like **JSDoc** create.

`--coverageDirectory=../outside_folder_path/_test_report_/` flag will generate report like **JSDoc** create in your given folder_path.

Sample test report

[image: Sample test report]